# The rstudio tag should be renamed

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

The [rstudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rstudio) tag is routinely used by new R users who are using the RStudio front-end, and don't realize that it is different from [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r).  This overwhelms the users who actually follow the guidelines, which say "**Do not** use this tag for general R programming problems, just use the R tag. ONLY use for RStudio-specific questions."

I have been editing misplaced posts, but I stopped doing that on May 22.  Since then, I would say that only 1 out of about 17 questions follow the description of the tag.

I suggest that [rstudio-ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rstudio-ide) be added for questions about the RStudio IDE.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess this rename wouldn't help. Keep in mind that the tag field has autocompletion. Askers who are genuinely confused and that fail to notice the tag description will begin typing "rstudio", see [rstudio-ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rstudio-ide) on the popup, click on it and move on. Other common reasons for this kind of tag misuse are askers genuinely overestimating the importance of their IDE to their questions, and askers adding anything that seems vaguely related to their problem. Adding a suffix to the tag name is unlikely to make a difference in such cases either.

I do empathise with your predicament: over at [haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell), we regularly get questions tagged with [haskell-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell-platform), [haskell-stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell-stack), [template-haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/template-haskell) or [ghci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ghci) that have nothing to do with the corresponding tools/toolchains/features -- not to mention that, in comparison, the [rstudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rstudio) situation seems quite a bit worse in terms of volume of questions. I don't know of a good way to make this issue easier to manage; it would be helpful to hear of success stories, if they exist.

Comment: Sad but true. It's like the [tag:xcode] tag.

Comment: You're probably right, but I'll leave your answer unaccepted for a few days in the hope of hearing a success story.