# What should we do about oft-misused tags?

Tags: discussion

For some reason, the vast majority of questions tagged [haskell-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell-platform) and/or [haskell-stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell-stack) are actually beginner questions about Haskell that have absolutely nothing to do with the [Haskell Platform](https://www.haskell.org/platform/) or the [Haskell Tool Stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org/).

I can remove the tags, but it gets pretty annoying. Anyone who's actually an expert at these things has probably long since quit paying attention to the tags, since there are so many more false positives than relevant questions. Could we do something about that?

My first thought is that some tags should only be applied by users with at least 100 rep earned on the site. It might even be possible to do this automatically, by tracking how often each tag is removed from a question.

Comment: *"My first thought is that some tags should only be applied by users with at least 100 rep earned on the site."* So what happens when a new user wants to ask a question that *is* about [tag:haskell-platform] and/or [tag:haskell-stack]? We just send them away as we assume they don't have the reputation to know the difference between [tag:haskell] and the aforementioned tags..? (New) Users using tags incorrectly isn't a new thing; I edit plenty of questions to remove conflicting tags. There needs to be a warning when people do it but SE won't ever implement that (it's been asked for many times).

Comment: I remember having mentioned [haskell-platform] and [haskell-stack] as examples of this problem [in a related discussion some time ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/368635). I tend to agree with Makoto's answer on there unfortunately not being much to be done about it. FWIW, I have edited the [haskell-stack] tag excerpt so that it provides usage guidance -- it's not clear how much that will actually help, but it is worth trying anyway.

Comment: @Larnu, these questions are generally also tagged [haskell]. This is sufficient for a more experienced user to see them and add the missing tags.

Comment: That makes it *worse* @dfeuer ... You specifically said you get annoyed by having to remove [tag:haskell] from questions that's not about it, but you're "ok" with checking ***every*** [tag:haskell] question to see if it's about something else? That's far more work and *requires* moderation (from users) to get the questions to the people watching the tags that they can answer. No. Just No...

Comment: @Larnu, no, I said I'm annoyed about having to remove [tag:haskell-stack] and [tag:haskell-platform] from questions that are generally already appropriately tagged [tag:haskell].

Comment: That isn't how your question comes across at all, @dfeuer. It comes across that you are someone who uses  [tag:haskell-stack] and/or [tag:haskell-platform] and are fed up of questions about [tag:Haskell].

Comment: @Larnu, I personally know very little about either. I follow the [tag:haskell] tag and see those pasted onto every other beginner question based on some "more tags better" notion.

Answer (score 7):

"People who ask questions about this technology need to have at least 100 reputation before they can ask questions about this technology."

This...is an intractable problem.  To get help for a problem, you must be reasonably expert in other arenas completely unrelated to your problem.

There's [about a million users who have 100 reputation or more](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1407858), which might *sound* like a lot, but that pales in comparison to the additional **13 million others** who come up less than that.

So instead of doing anything technical with looking at a person's reputation or looking at how many times someone looks at tags, the *simplest* and likely most effective approach is to continue doing what you're doing - if the tags are not being applied appropriately, then *edit them out*.  If you choose not to, then that's fine too - the hope is that other Haskell users who are as expert as you are *and* are also committed to question quality will take up that mantle instead.

Comment: These questions can always be tagged [haskell], and anyone who's not brand new can add the appropriate tags.

Comment: That dig at the end is pretty mean. I'm quite committed to question quality. This is a particular mindless annoyance that seems like it could just go away, letting us deal manually with more involved question quality issues.

Comment: @dfeuer:  I wasn't attacking you.  I was suggesting that if you didn't want to do it anymore, hopefully someone else would.  I don't like the philosophy of working for cheap or for free, and that's what you'd be doing.  So if you don't want to keep doing it, you don't *have* to.